# Post Hoc Kruskal - Wallis test for compare mean ranks

Tags: nonparametric, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

Can I use multiple comparison (Post Hoc Test) if Kruskal - Wallis Test can only be used to compare mean ranks?